# Better way to access break-on-exception filter when debugging in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, exception

I'm tired of using the eye-squinting, time-consuming Exceptions dialog in Visual Studio to turn break-on-exception filters on and off. I looked for a Visual Studio command to help automate this from the Command window, but no luck.

Does anyone have a technique for avoiding the Debug->Exceptions dialog yet get access to its functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the Wintellect gurus (John Robbins) posted about [customizing exception handling](http://www.wintellect.com/CS/blogs/jrobbins/archive/2009/04/03/customizing-exception-handling-in-the-vs-debugger.aspx) with macros.  It provides a nice way of setting those without going into the dialog.  It seems a bit slow on my machine ... although no slower than going and hunting down a specific exception in that dialog.

Comment: This looks like it has decent potential. If the macro is too sluggish, at least I now know about, and have examples to program against, the Debugger3 interface, which is what I was ultimately looking for.