# How to save and manage Debug->Exceptions preferences in VS2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, exception

By example: 
1. I'm fixing a bug and need to break on exceptions. I set to break on all exceptions.
2. Then I decided do not break on some exceptions and disabled them.
3. I solved the bug and disabled all exceptions. Oops, all preferences are gone.
4. I found another bug and need to repeat really annoying step 2.

So, how to avoid repeating of the step 2?

Comment: It seems my question is duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2004618/better-way-to-access-break-on-exception-filter-when-debugging-in-visual-studio. Although, the answer there isn't very promising. Just don't have time to test it now.

Comment: Step 3, don't disable all exceptions.  Kinda doh.

Comment: Unfortunately those are stored in the binary `.suo` file (at least in vs2008) so you can't manage them externally as you could if they were in the registry.  I think your only real option would be to write an add-in.

Answer (score 1):

This is partial but still quite useful answer on my question. Last week I was working on the program which generates a lot of exceptions on start up. I don't need to see them. But after the start I need to see all exceptions. So, I've wrote simple AutoHotkey script which just toggles main groups of exceptions when global hotkey pressed (Ctrl+Alt+e):

```
msvs:="Microsoft Visual Studio"
ex:="Exceptions"

^!e::
SetTitleMatchMode, 2

WinActivate, %msvs%
WinWaitActive, %msvs%
Send ^d
Sleep, 200
Send e
WinWaitActive, %ex%
Click  396 100
Click  396 120
Click  396 160
Click  396 180
Click  620 60
return
```